# How to get the filtered object into the json-server when an end user does a rough search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

I am using json-server as my fake API data. I am implementing the search functionality to it. I created an endpoint like this -

```
getData : ( searchTerm : string ) => axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/books?=${searchTerm}`).then((response) => setData(response));
```

and I am utilizing into my input field to get the searched results.

Let's say My json object coming back from the Json-server is as follows -

```
[
{
"Id": 1,
"name" : "car"
},
{
"Id": 2,
"name" : "bike"
},
{
"Id": 3,
"name" : "ninja bike"
}]
```

now, the problem is , when I search for "car", it gives me the json result.
but, when I search for "brand new car", it should give me the "car's" object at least, as word "car" is a match. but it is giving me [], empty array.

So please suggest me how could i look for specific words into my json-server's data?
so that whenever , the end user even make a vague unstructured search, it should look for specific words like "car", in this case and return that car object.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple filter to check if your string is in there

```js
let json = [{
        "Id": 1,
        "name": "car"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "name": "bike"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "name": "ninja bike"
    }
]
let searchString = "brand new car".split(" ") // ["brand", "new", "car"]

let filter = json.filter(json => searchString.includes(json.name))

if (filter.length) {
    console.log(filter[0].name)
    console.log(filter[0].Id)
}
else console.log("not found")
```

Comment: I think your method is suitable for applying the search results for the local data, which is present into our browser. How could we make such functonality before fetching live data from json server. I mean , how could we split up the data and then make every request to json-server to fetch for word that matches anywhere into the entire string?   isn't plenty number of requests to api server?

Comment: @HimanshuSharma i gave you some example code, you figure it out yourself how you want to implement it on your server